# Showing a div on hover over another div is causing multiple requests to the server and flicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a div float next to another div on hover. My divs are basically like a grid, several divs placed next to each other.
below is my fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/dfe2t1ha/3/

I'm using plain javascript and I basically want to show another div `div2` floating next to `div1` on hover.

ex:

```
<div class="div1" onmouseover=getDetails()>

  </div>
  <div class="div2">

  </div>

function getDetails() {
 let html ="";
  return fetch('https://www.google.com')
  .then((response)=> {
    response.json().then((data) => {
      html += `
    <div>Hello world</div>

      `;
      document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[index].innerHTML = html;
      document.getElementsByClassName("div2")[index].style.display = "block";

    });

  });
}
```

but when I try to show `display: block` on `div2` I see that its making multiple request calls to the server and its fetching the url multiple times and I see flicker on hover.I beleiev its due to the several calls it as making to the server
I'm not sure exactly where the problem lies.is there a way we could fix this with css or its a js issue?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that you need to use a throttle function. If you are fetching on mouseover, you are probably doing it hudred times a second. But maybe I misunderstood your question.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with throttle function, and yes I'm fetching data from server on mouseover, If I do add static data into the html template, it works fine, only the fetch inside the func is causing the issue, Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: See [this Medium article about throttle & debounce](https://codeburst.io/throttling-and-debouncing-in-javascript-b01cad5c8edf). And sorry, I was wrong about the *hunderd times a second*, I was probably order (or two) off (I was thinking about mousemove).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```js
window.requestInProgress = false;
document.getElementById('targetHoverComponent').addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
 if (window.requestInProgess !== true) {
   document.getElementById('targetConentComponent').innerHTML='Loading....';
    getDetailsAsync().then((bio) => {
     document.getElementById('targetConentComponent').innerHTML=bio; //Do make sure to get it checked for xss attacks.
    });
  }
});

async function getDetailsAsync() {
 console.log('inside async');
  window.requestInProgress = true;
  const response = await fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/saurabhnemade`);
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();
  //console.log(jsonResponse.bio);
  window.requestInProgress = false;
  return await jsonResponse.bio;
}
```

```css
.search-component-row-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.search-component {
  padding: 10px;
}

.criteria {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.criteria-onhover {
  display: none;
}

.criteria:hover ~.criteria-onhover{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-component">
          <div class="search-component-row-container">
              <div class="criteria" id="targetHoverComponent">
                Div on which hover is required
              </div>
              <div class="criteria-onhover" id="targetConentComponent">
                Hidden Div Contents which appears on hover
              </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

Link to working fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/j05mg1xy/3/

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a ton!